# Should I call IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync() in Program.cs using JS module?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, webassembly, iasyncdisposable

I need to configure localization in Blazor WASM, .NET 6

[According to the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference), I need to use JavaScript in the `Program.cs` file. Microsoft recommends connecting JavaScript code through [JavaScript isolation in JavaScript modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules). However, the code specified in the example is the Blazor component, and `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()` is called there

Do I need to call `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()` in `Program.cs` and if so, how to do it without resorting to creating the `Program` class and the `Main` method, but using a new version of the console program template?

Answer (score 1):

The question is very stupid on my part. I didn't see the most obvious solution.

You can just call the DisposeAsync() method manually when the object is no longer needed.

As a result, the code will look like this. The code is slightly different from [the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference), so part of the logic is placed in a separate class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

using Store.Client;
using Store.Client.Engine;

using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddLocalization();

var host = builder.Build();

var js = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
var module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/scripts.js");

var culture = await module.InvokeAsync<string>("getCulture");

if (culture is not null)
{
    Culture.Current = new CultureInfo(culture);
}
else
{
    Culture.Current = Culture.Default;

    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("setCulture", Culture.Current.Name);
}
    
await module.DisposeAsync();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: consider using the using keyword: `await using var module = await js.InvokeAsync(...)`